# Adding a collection of collections to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I'm trying to make a program that takes a User class with parameters name, username, password and email to create a HashMap containing this information. The key will be the name of the User and the value will be an ArrayList containing information about the user (username, password, email). This class should provide a method to create a new user, which can be utilised from a PasswordDB class, which creates an Array of Users and their information by calling this method.

This is the code for the User class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User
{
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;    
    private ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> userInfo = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

public User(String name, String username, String password, String email)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    this.email=email;
}

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> addUser()
{        
    arr.add(username);
    arr.add(password);
    arr.add(email);
    userInfo.put(name, arr);
    return userInfo;
    }
}
```

And for the PasswordDB class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PasswordDB
{
    private ArrayList<User> database;
    private User newUser;

public PasswordDB()
{
    ArrayList<User> database = new ArrayList<User>();
}

public void newUser(String name ,String username ,String password ,String email)
{
    User newUser = new User(name, username, password, email);
    database.add(newUser.addUser());
    }
}
```

And I receive the following error in the PasswordDB class:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atoTT.png)

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Change `database.add(newUser.addUser());` to `database.add(newUser);`?

Comment: You are trying to add a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` to a `List<User>`. `User.addUser` returns a `HashMap`. I think you have made this more complicated than it needs to be, I'm confused about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This compiles now but returns a NullPointerException

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I didn't realise that. I'm trying to use a hashmap so that I can search up users to find their information based on their names.

Comment: `ArrayList<User> database = new ArrayList<User>();` shadows the field in your constructor. Remove the type on the left-hand side. `database = new ArrayList<User>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this program a lot. A user does not need to know anything about any other user, so no list or database should be in the `User` class.

Have a `User` class that has properties for name, username, password, email and nothing else. It's just data about a user.

Then a `PasswordDB` class with your hashmap and just map a username to a user, you don't need all these extra lists.

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private String username;
    // ..

    public User(String name, String username, ...) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        // ...
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    // .. more getters
}

public class PasswordDB {
    private HashMap<String,User> userInfo = new HashMap<String,User>();

    public void addUser(User newUser) {
        userInfo.put(newUser.getUsername(), newUser);
    }

    // maybe you need to get a user by username
    public User getUser(String username) {
        return userInfo.get(username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying to add a `HashMap` into the `ArrayList`!

Try the following

```
public void newUser(String name ,String username ,String password ,String email)
  {
    User newUser = new User(name, username, password, email);
    newUser.addUser();
    database.add(newUser);
  }
```

Comment: Why create and throw away the `HashMap` though?

Comment: As per his class design! I just wrote the fix of his exception here.

Comment: Dang! I thought you knew what that was for.

Answer (score 0):

change your PasswordDB class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PasswordDB
{
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> database;
    private User newUser;

public PasswordDB()
{
     database = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void newUser(String name ,String username ,String password ,String email)
{
    User newUser = new User(name, username, password, email);
    database.add(newUser.addUser());
    }
}
```